# module.exports http not defined when creating server

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I'm trying to understand how to use module.exports in nodejs. I have this line of code in app.js

```
// Creating the server 
var createServer = require('./moduleExports/creatingServer');
createServer();
```

and this code in another file, creatingServer.js

```
module.exports = function() {

socketServer = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function() { 
    console.log("Express server listening at %s:%d ", app.get('ip'), app.get('port'));
}); 

}
```

there's more but I cut it out. I'm getting an error when I run `node app.js`, it's saying that `http` is not defined. I required it in the app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

change your creatingServer.js to:

```
var http = require('http');
module.exports = function() {

    socketServer = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'),     function() { 
        console.log("Express server listening at %s:%d ", app.get('ip'),     app.get('port'));
   }); 

}
```

Node.js files aren't aware of code outside of themselves. `require('http')` pulls in that module and allows you to use it in the file.

You're also using an `app` variable, which isn't really required for a basic http server and looks like you've copied code from an `express` example?

Comment: that's weird, I need to require express then too...I have to do that twice. Isn't there a way to move out some code into another file?